# Как увеличить скорость выполнения скрипта PHP?

Tags: php, apache, оптимизация

Характеристики сервера:
Intel Xeon 6 ядер по 2,2 ГГц
Оперативная память DDR4 12ГБ
Дисковое пространство NVMe 100Gb
Я программист такой себе, знаете ли... Увы, не шарю в квотах и пропускной способности линии, надеюсь у меня с этим всё нормально.
**Рассказываю:**
Сайт у меня на laravel, на *index.php* есть обычные две кнопки, на которых работает *Ajax*, передающий методом POST 3 *integer* значения и тип кнопки и соответственно ждёт ответ от конкретной функции где всё и выполняется. Вообщем чего уж таить, сайт рулетка типа nVuti, что бы вы лучше понимали о чём идёт речь. Хотелось бы спросить, может быть, как-нибудь можно настроить *php.ini* или *apache2*, не знаю что, что бы ускорить время выполнение скрипта? Если вы собираетесь давать ответ, то не рекомендуйте изначально оптимизацию кода, а ответьте на конкретный вопрос. Если же нельзя никак ускорить по моему вопросу, с удовольствием послушаю советы по оптимизации. Для меня это очень интересно. Просто, я считаю, что *success* от функции в 1.29s это много. Неужели мой сервер не способен обрабатывать быстрее всё это дело? Всегда приятно послушать умных людей. Кстати, может это из какого-нибудь ограничения HTTP запроса? Всё работает через порт **80**[image: Профилирование, надеюсь так выглядит]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84011/discussion-on-question-by-roman-kashirov-----).

Comment: чего тут обсуждать сферического коня в вакууме. что код-то делает этот? сколько пустой экшен отрабатывает по времени. включите пхп 7, если вдруг у вас до сих пор 5й, включите opcache. Не приведя код, вы не получите здесь ответа на свой вопрос.